# Counter reset in php

Tags: php, loops, counter, reset

I have a script that counts the number of times you visit a page, what i would like to do is for the counter to reset whenever it riches 5. ie (count from 1-5) and reset's back to 1. any ideas?

```
$handle = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');

    flock($handle, LOCK_EX);

        $total = (int) fread($handle, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));

        $newTotal = ++$total;

        rewind($handle);

        fwrite($handle, $newTotal);

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: What is your issue? Where do you hit the roadblock? And what has the submit to do with the problem? I have no clue, so I removed it from the example.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple ,

You can do it using

```
    $handle = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');

    flock($handle, LOCK_EX);

        $total = (int) fread($handle, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));
        if($total==5){
            fwrite($handle, 1);
        }
        else{
        $newTotal = ++$total;

        rewind($handle);

        fwrite($handle, $newTotal);
        }
fclose($f);
```

Comment: let me try, i will let you know how it oes. thanx a lot

Comment: @arkascha - it's not, plus your comment doesn't help with the original question or the answer.

Comment: @N.B. ok, if you say so. In my eyes it is more safe and it is actually common practise to note comparisions that way round. But maybe there are reasons for you denying it?

Comment: okay, im trying with this code but its not writing 1 to file, any idea

Comment: @N.B. how can i do it, im trying to reset as it reaches 5

Comment: $handle = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');

    flock($handle, LOCK_EX);

        $total = (int) fread($handle, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));
  if($total==5){
   fwrite($handle, 1);
  }
  else{
        $newTotal = ++$total;

        rewind($handle);

        fwrite($handle, $newTotal);
  }
fclose($f);

Comment: @arkascha - It's not common practice, this isn't a discussion about practices or preferences, it's about solving a problem. If you want to discuss whether constant comes before variable in a condition or vice-versa, there's programmers.stackexchange.com and you can discuss it there. Ree - there are 2 answers explaining it, use the examples and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: @N.B. I never tried to argue. I made an enhancement suggestion. Just denying common practise like you do without giving a reason as I asked you to does not really help too. Sorry.

Comment: @arkascha - It's not enhancement suggestion nor is it common practice, it's called something else and it has to do with feces and other excrements. There's no point in polluting this answer any further, if you wish to discuss the matter further - there are places to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
flock($f, LOCK_EX);
$total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    rewind($f);
    $total = ($total >= 5)? 1 : $total++; // Increment or reset
    fwrite($f, $total); // Write new value
}

fclose($f);
```